# Url is not entering after firefox invoked in java by Selenium

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Firefox was launched but the url is not entering in the address bar. I'm using selenium 2.45 and firefox 39

Answer (score 0):

As per change log selenium 2.45 has firefox support upto 35, but you are using firefox39. try with version 35 or less

"Selenium 2.45.0
* Firefox support up to 35, support for native events up to 34."

link of change log: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/py/CHANGES

Comment: can you create a new firefox profile and try. here is a link to create profile: http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/

Answer (score 0):

upgrade selenium to 2.46, should solve your issue